# Getchar() keeps returning 1

Tags: c, getchar

i am new to StackOverflow. I hope to be able to learn a lot here.
So, i'm a beginner in C. I'm just trying a few things, like using very basic functions.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{   int c;
    int i,wl[20];
    int count = 0;
   i = 0;

printf("Insert line: ");    


while(c= getchar() != '\n'&& c != EOF)
    printf("integer value of the variable is %d\n", c);
return 0;
}
```

This should be an easy program: you insert an input and gives you the current value in int.
The problem is: getchar keeps returning 1, no matter what.
[image]

Also, i have another question. I know that char in C is basically an 8 bit integer and as a matter of fact you can using char and int (with some problems, as integer are not 8 bit variables) interchangeably. So: why do some people declare a variable as int instead of char when in need to store a char with getchar? Sorry for such basic questions.

N.B: other variables are declared as this is part of a bigger code. all the other parts of the code were put as code in order to test this (/* */). 
Sorry for my English, i hope what i wrote is clear.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please to not post images of plain text. Instead simply copy&paste the text into your question. This applies to code as well as the output of your program.

Comment: Please do not put multiple questions into a single question. Create a new one instead.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int` value, not a `char`. That should be reason enough. Also please think about this: Does `EOF` fit into a `char`?

Comment: Ok, next time i will create new thread and post text instead of images. I see your point with the EOF example.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
c= getchar() != '\n'
```

is equivalent to

```
c = (getchar() != '\n')
```

so not at all what you meant. So the `1` is the result of the `!=` comparison. You need

```
(c = getchar()) != '\n'
```

Comment: oh wow. It was that easy. Thank you very much, i really do appreciate. I have been trying to solve this for at least an hour.